# When I run my Airflow, no task is created

Tags: task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a problem, the demo is very simple, but after deployment on the airflow, execution does not achieve the desired effect. Here's my code

```
"""
import pytz
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.operators.latest_only_operator import LatestOnlyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
dt = datetime.now(tz)
utc_dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'syroot',
    "start_date": utc_dt - timedelta(minutes=2),
    "depends_on_past": False,
    'email': ['zhaosw@sunnyoptical.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    "demo1",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="*/2 * * * *",
)


def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'


hello_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id='hello_task',
    python_callable=print_hello,
    dag=dag)

"""
```

But the results were not so good, dag run success, but no task create. I can not find any info in task instances menu, but I can find dag run log in DAG Runs menu.

[image]

Comment: A title of "Who can help me please" is not useful. When asking questions here, try to ask a specific and focussed question about what _exactly_ the problem is. I have tried to summarise the precise nature of the problem, but do please edit it again if I have not understood your description correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe your scheduler is able to run the DAG due to your dynamic start date.

Try changing `"start_date": utc_dt - timedelta(minutes=2),` to a static date like `"start_date": datetime(2019,12,9),`. That should allow the scheduler to pick it up!

It's generally recommended not to set your start_date dynamically.

Taken from Airflow FAQ:

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially
>   datetime.now()  as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered
>   once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get
>   to an hour after now as now() moves along.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which task execute. It looks like you are missing:

```
hello_operator
```

in your DAG:

```
def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'


hello_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id='hello_task',
    python_callable=print_hello,
    dag=dag)

hello_operator # <-- add this
```

Comment: They do not need to specify orchestration. Orchestration is used for organizing tasks how you want them to be run, otherwise the scheduler runs them as it sees fit. Orchestration is not needed by default.